# MATLAB : Creating database for extracted features

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I need to know what are the procedures to saves values extracted using a extraction method. Dear people I really need the help.

I'm using *GLCM* to extract features from an image, they include :

*`Autocorrelation, Contrast, Correlation, Cluster Prom. etc.`*

```
   autoc: 3.900316455696202e+00
    contr: 1.091772151898734e+00
    corrm: 4.581568547804957e-01
    corrp: 4.581568547804950e-01
    cprom: 2.281526081422013e+01
    cshad: 3.969992738911119e+00
    dissi: 6.835443037974684e-01
    energ: 1.564853388879987e-01
    entro: 2.304539365626317e+00
    homom: 7.199367088607593e-01
    homop: 6.990506329113924e-01
   ....
```

But I don't know the procedures to save these value into database (dataset?).

So that later I can compared these values to input/test image features.

I'm searching over the internet but couldn't afford to solve this mainly because facilitation of the new *`Image Processing Toolbox`* which is not available to my old matlab.

My intepretation for the procedures are:

- Extract  each of the feature values
- Save them in a file called database (dataset?)
- Iterate over the values  and apply simple classification.

But right now I don't know how to save these values in a database as the later input to a classifier.

Comment: So you *have* extracted the features, and your question is how to save these efficiently, right? As you seem to have a rather old Matlab, can you please tell us which version it is?

Comment: I have matlab R2008a and ( temporary borrowed R2013a for 6 months) , I need help to saves the values

Comment: In general, you can just use `save` to save any values to a file. If you have want to save the same features for many images, you could make a `struct` and save this.

Comment: Hi thanks could you give it through an asnwer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [`struct`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct.html) is well suited to save such data, e.g.

```
database = struct('autoc', 3.900316455696202, 'contr', 1.091772151898734, ...)
```

On the help page of [`struct`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct.html), there are more examples on how one can fill data into a struct, depending on how you get your data in the first place.
You could e.g. first create an empty struct with pre-defined fields:

```
database = struct('autoc',{},'contr',{},'corrm',{}, ...)
```

and then add data with

```
database(1).autoc = 3.900316455696202;
database(1).contr = 1.091772151898734;
...
```

and for the next image:

```
database(2).autoc = 3.900316455696202;
database(2).contr = 1.091772151898734;
...
```

So, you'll have one struct array in your workspace, which contains all your data. You can access the data e.g. with 
`database(1)`,
which returns all features of the first image.
You can directly access features with `database(1).autoc`.
Then, you can get the `autoc` field of all images with `[database(:).autoc]`.

To save this database to a file, you can use the [`save`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html) function, which is simply

```
save('your_filename.mat', 'database')
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Thank you!